# Ubuntu 13.04 Clean install Pandora does not work

Tags: installation, 13.04, chromium, pandora, adblock

Simply put pandora is not working this is the error they give me, "We've encountered an error. Sorry, it's our fault. Please click 'reload' to continue listening." of course I hit reload and it does not work.

More info...
Everything was working fine running 12.04 then I did a system upgrade to 13.04 once the upgrade was complete Pandora among other this did not work. Then I went the extra step and backed up all files on an external hard-drive and did a format and a clean install, Still the problem persists. any ideas or help would be great.

...I am running chromium w/ ad blocked and hover zoom. I also just tried groveshark.com and this music playing website works with no issues.

Thank you
pow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as you (except it was working on 13.04 for a while, until something changed). The solution for me was luckily simple:

sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra

This will replace the chromium-codecs-ffmpeg package with the above. Hope it works for you, enjoy Pandora! :)

Comment: Thank you so much that that worked perfectly (once i restarted my browser)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!